# dplyr: mutate from multiple areas/characters of a substring

Tags: r, dplyr, substr, case-when

A beginner here. Trying to use dplyr: mutate/case_when which has multiple substring conditions (10-character string). Each character represents an ethnicity. For example, a string with a "Y" in any of the 1-3 positions of the string and a "N" in the rest would be defined as "Latino". I am trying to get the correct code for a string which has a "Y" in any of the 1-3 positions but also a "Y" say in either of 4-5 positions ("Asian"). I want to define this as "Multi-Ethnic". Would appreciate in providing the correct code to create for a string which has an outcome of "Multi-Ethnic"? Many thanks for this site!

```
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(APP_AC = c("YNNNNNNNNN",
                             "YYNNNNNNNN",
                             "YYYNNNNNNN",
                             "YNYNNNNNNN",
                             "NNNYNNNNNN",
                             "YNNYNNNNNN",
                             "NNNNNYNNNN",
                             "YNNNNYNNNY",
                             "NNNNNNNNNN"))

data %>% 
  mutate(ETHNICITY = case_when(
    str_sub(APP_AC,1,1) == "Y" ~ "Latino", 
    str_sub(APP_AC,2,2) == "Y" ~ "Latino",
    str_sub(APP_AC,3,3) == "Y" ~ "Latino",
    str_sub(APP_AC,4,4) == "Y" ~ "Asian",
    str_sub(APP_AC,5,5) == "Y" ~ "Asian",
    str_sub(APP_AC,6,6) == "Y" ~ "Black",
    str_sub(APP_AC,7,7) == "Y" ~ "Native_American_Alaskan",
    str_sub(APP_AC,8,8) == "Y" ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_sub(APP_AC,9,9) == "Y" ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_sub(APP_AC,10,10) == "Y" ~ "White",
    TRUE ~ "Unknown"))

    APP_AC     ETHNICITY
1   YNNNNNNNNN Latino
2   YYNNNNNNNN Latino
3   YYYNNNNNNN Latino
4   YNYNNNNNNN Latino
5   NNNYNNNNNN Asian
6   YNNYNNNNNN Asian
7   NNNNNYNNNN Black
8   YNNNNYNNNY Latino
9   NNNNNNNNNN Unknown
```

Desired output:

```
    APP_AC     ETHNICITY
1   YNNNNNNNNN Latino
2   YYNNNNNNNN Latino
3   YYYNNNNNNN Latino
4   YNYNNNNNNN Latino
5   NNNYNNNNNN Asian
6   YNNYNNNNNN Multi-Ethnic
7   NNNNNYNNNN Black
8   YNNNNYNNNY Multi-Ethnic
9   NNNNNNNNNN Unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to include logic described in comments and updated question.

**CODE**

```
data %>% 
  mutate(ETHNICITY = case_when(
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 1, 3),"Y") & str_count(substr(APP_AC, 4, 10), "Y") == 0 ~ "Latino", 
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 1, 3),"Y") & str_count(substr(APP_AC, 4, 10), "Y") >= 1 ~ "Multi-Ethnic", 
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 4, 5),"Y")  ~ "Asian", 
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 6, 6),"Y") ~ "Black",
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 7, 7),"Y") ~ "Native_American_Alaskan",
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 8, 9),"Y") ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_detect(substr(APP_AC, 10, 10),"Y") ~ "White",
    TRUE ~ "Unknown")
  )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      APP_AC    ETHNICITY
1 YNNNNNNNNN       Latino
2 YYNNNNNNNN       Latino
3 YYYNNNNNNN       Latino
4 YNYNNNNNNN       Latino
5 NNNYNNNNNN        Asian
6 YNNYNNNNNN Multi-Ethnic
7 NNNNNYNNNN        Black
8 YNNNNYNNNY Multi-Ethnic
9 NNNNNNNNNN      Unknown
```

Comment: Yes I am looking for something that will address any string with multiple "Y" values (i.e. "YNNNYNNNNY", "YYNNYNNNYY") which may have any variation of the above 6 ethnic groups. Is there a simple way to do this? Thank you. @Russ Thomas

Comment: Hi @DIFC, I updated the last line to use ```str_count``` instead to update for any strings that have two or more occurrences of ```Y```. Give that a try and let me know if that works for your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Russ Thomas, its just that a string may have a "Y" in the two of the first 3 positions then the string should still be defined as "Latino" and not "Multi-Ethnic". Just to clarify: the positions 1-3 ("Latino"), 4-5 ("Asian") and so forth. Thank you.

Comment: Code updated to address 1-3 ("Latino"), 4-5 ("Asian"). So if any string has more than one ```Y``` will that always be ```multi-ethnic```?

Comment: Oops, had a typo, the first line in mutate should have had ```== 1``` instead of ```== 3```. Corrected now. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @Russ Thomas, I've updated my request with more examples - sorry new to this. So if 1-3 positions contains a "Y" then even with multiple "Y"s then it would be defined as "Latino" (i.e. YYNNNNNNNN). However if the string has 1-3 Y's in the 1-3 positions but also has a "Y" in the Asian positions (4-5) and/or Black position (6) and so forth then it would be defined as "Multi-Ethnic" (i.e. YYYNYYNNNN). Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I've updated my answer to attempt to address the needed logic.

Comment: Russ Thomas, @Ronak Shah: a combination of your answers helped me figure it out. Quite amazed how much you guys know - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_detect` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  mutate(ETHNICITY = case_when(
    str_count(APP_AC, 'Y') > 1 ~ "Multi-Ethnic",
    str_sub(APP_AC,1,1) == "Y" ~ "Latino", 
    str_sub(APP_AC,2,2) == "Y" ~ "Latino",
    str_sub(APP_AC,3,3) == "Y" ~ "Latino",
    str_sub(APP_AC,4,4) == "Y" ~ "Asian",
    str_sub(APP_AC,5,5) == "Y" ~ "Asian",
    str_sub(APP_AC,6,6) == "Y" ~ "Black",
    str_sub(APP_AC,7,7) == "Y" ~ "Native_American_Alaskan",
    str_sub(APP_AC,8,8) == "Y" ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_sub(APP_AC,9,9) == "Y" ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_sub(APP_AC,10,10) == "Y" ~ "White",
    TRUE ~ "Unknown"))

#      APP_AC    ETHNICITY
#1 YNNNNNNNNN       Latino
#2 NNNYNNNNNN        Asian
#3 YNNYNNNNNN Multi-Ethnic
#4 NNNNNYNNNN        Black
#5 NNNNNNNNNN      Unknown
```

Similarly, you can also combine other conditions into one to make the code shorter.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(ETHNICITY = case_when(
    str_count(APP_AC, 'Y') > 1 ~ "Multi-Ethnic",
    str_detect(str_sub(APP_AC, 1, 3), 'Y') ~ "Latino",
    str_detect(str_sub(APP_AC, 4, 5), 'Y') ~ "Asian",
    str_sub(APP_AC,6,6) == "Y" ~ "Black",
    str_sub(APP_AC,7,7) == "Y" ~ "Native_American_Alaskan",
    str_detect(str_sub(APP_AC, 8, 9), 'Y') ~ "Pacific_Islander",
    str_sub(APP_AC,10,10) == "Y" ~ "White",
    TRUE ~ "Unknown"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah I am looking for something that will address any string with multiple "Y" values (i.e. "YNNNYNNNNY", "YYNNYNNNYY") which may have any variation of the above 6 ethnic groups and will be defined as "Multi-Ethnic". Is there a simple way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: @DIFC In that case you can use `str_count`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ronak Shah, its just that a string may have a "Y" in the two of the first 3 positions then the string should still be defined as "Latino" and not "Multi-Ethnic". Just to clarify: the positions 1-3 ("Latino"), 4-5 ("Asian") and so forth. Thank you

Comment: @DIFC, if positions 1-3 are all "Y" what would that be classified as?  i.e. ```YYYNNNNNNN```. Can you add more specific examples in your input and expected output to cover these various additional requirements?